# React-Node.js API store dispatch issue: post request needs 2 attempts to store data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux, axios

**Update**
Even after the correct suggestion to modify the setClientData reducer in a non-mutating way, the problem stays the same. I also added totalItems and totalPrice to clientData so that orderData can be completely replaced by clientData

[image]

```
setClientData: (state,action) => {
        const {payload} = action;
        return { ...state, orderData: { ...payload } }
    },
```

**Original question**

I'm a programming student and as an assignment I need to make a very simple webshop (no authentication or paying method) using React and a Node.js Express Web API + MySQL (everything runs on localhost).

Everything works fine but there is one bug I can't get my head around. I always need to press the "place order button" twice for it to work.

The first time you click the button, there is a status 400 response that comes from the express-validator because the client data which is gathered through input text fields appears to be empty. When you click the button again, it does work. The problem does not occur using Postman so the problem is in the React-application, more specifically when the user data is being stored in the shopping cart slice (cartState) in the redux store.

In Confirm.jsx, after the user enters his/her data (and after front-end validation) I use a dispatch "setClientData" with the data that updates the cartState.

To debug this problem, I did some console.log's in 2 different moments: once before the axios POST and once after.

At the first attempt, the data seems to not have been stored successfully in the cartState. "firstName" etc. is empty and we get a 400 response. "totalPrice" and "totalItems" do have the correct value but those had already been stored in the cartState at a previous step).

However, I also used some console.log's during the "setClientData" dispatch and then the data does seem to have been stored successfully in the cartState.

At the second POST-attemt, "firstName" etc. is being stored successfully in the cartState and then also in the database.

I really don't understand how this is possible since a dispatch is a synchronous process I believe so I don't think the first console.log's are being done too soon and I also don't see how the axios POST could influence the cartState somehow that it would work the second time.

I would appreciate any insight on this matter, thank you in advance!

**store/cart/slice.js:**

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'cart',
    initialState: {
        orderLines: {},
        orderData: {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            street: "",
            number: "",
            postalCode: "",
            city: "",
            telephone: "",
            email: "",
            totalPrice: 0,
            totalItems: 0
        }
    },
    reducers: {

        setClientData: (state,action) => {
            const {payload} = action;
            console.log("payloadFirstName: "+payload.firstName);
            state.orderData.firstName = payload.firstName;
            console.log("stateFirstName: "+state.orderData.firstName);
            state.orderData.lastName = payload.lastName;
            state.orderData.street = payload.street;
            state.orderData.number = payload.number;
            state.orderData.postalCode = payload.postalCode;
            state.orderData.city = payload.city;
            state.orderData.telephone = payload.telephone;
            state.orderData.email = payload.email;
        },
```

**Confirm.jsx:**

```
if (everythingFilledOutCorrectly) {

            const clientData = {
                firstName: inputFields[0].value.trim(),
                lastName: inputFields[1].value.trim(),
                street: inputFields[2].value.trim(),
                number: inputFields[3].value.trim(),
                postalCode: inputFields[4].value.trim(),
                city: inputFields[5].value.trim(),
                email: inputFields[6].value.trim(),
                telephone: inputFields[7].value.trim(),
            }
            
            store.dispatch(setClientData(clientData));
            console.log("firstName1: "+cartState.orderData.firstName);
            console.log("totalItems: "+cartState.orderData.totalItems);
            console.log("totalPrice: "+cartState.orderData.totalPrice);

            //Place order in database  
            axios.post('http://localhost:3001/order', cartState)
            .then(response => {
                
                console.log("firstName2: "+cartState.orderData.firstName);
                console.log("totalItems: "+cartState.orderData.totalItems);
                console.log("totalPrice: "+cartState.orderData.totalPrice);

                if (response.status===200) {
                    //empty cart
                    store.dispatch(emptyCart());

                    //go to confirmation page
                    history.push(`/confirmation/${response.data}`);
                }
                else alert("Something went wrong.");
            })

            
         }
```

**chrome developer tools**
[image: chrome developer tools]

Comment: what is clientData before you dispatch it? Also notice that the redux reducer must return a new state, not mutate the initial

Answer (score 0):

Redux reducers must not mutate the initial state:

```
setClientData: (state,action) => {
        const {payload} = action;
        console.log("payloadFirstName: "+payload.firstName);
        state.orderData.firstName = payload.firstName;
        console.log("stateFirstName: "+state.orderData.firstName);
        state.orderData.lastName = payload.lastName;
        state.orderData.street = payload.street;
        state.orderData.number = payload.number;
        state.orderData.postalCode = payload.postalCode;
        state.orderData.city = payload.city;
        state.orderData.telephone = payload.telephone;
        state.orderData.email = payload.email;
    },
```

instead replace with this

```
setClientData: (state,action) => {
        const {payload} = action;
        return { ...state, orderData: { ...payload } }
    },
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did what you advised but the problem remains exactly the same.